$\operatorname{Hom}_{G}(V,W) \cong \operatorname{Hom}{G}(\mathbf{1},V^* \otimes W)$
Let $G$ be a group with some completely reducible finite-dimensional representations $V,W$, and let $\mathbf{1}$ be the trivial irreducible representation. I'm trying to make sense of the following seemingly standard identity referenced by N. Snyder and Q.Yuan:
Claim: $\operatorname{Hom}_{G}(V,W) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{G}(\mathbf{1},V^{*} \otimes W)$
I'm looking for hints as to how to approach the proof of this claim.
Aside / extra discussion: does this have anything to do with "internal homs" and "tensor-hom adjunctions"?
Updates:

The user FShrike has provided an answer that involvess taking bases and rolling up sleeves (thanks FShrike!).
I'll hopefully manage to add a basis-free answer shortly. [Added below].

Basis-free approach:
I'll show that $\operatorname{Hom}_{G}(V,W)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{G}(W\otimes V^{*},\mathbf{1})$. We know that elements of $W\otimes V^{*}$ can be identified with elements of $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$ via $(w \otimes \psi)(v)=\psi(v)\cdot w$ for $v\in V, w\in W, \psi\in V^{*}$. Now, $w\otimes\psi$ is $G$-linear if and only if $w\otimes \psi = \rho_{W}(g^{-1})(w\otimes \psi)\rho_{V}(g)$ for all $g\in G$, i.e. iff
$w\otimes \psi = \rho_{W}(g^{-1})|_{w}\otimes \rho_{V^{*}}(g^{-1})|_{\psi} = \rho_{W\otimes V^{*}}(g^{-1})|_{w\otimes \psi} \ \ , \ \ g\in G$
This shows that the subspace of $G$-linear maps in $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$ consists precisely of the elements of $W\otimes V^{*}$ which are $G$-invariant. This is the subspace comprising a direct sum of $m$ trivial irreps, where $m=\dim \operatorname{Hom}_{G}(W\otimes V^{*},\mathbf{1})$. $\square$

Sorry about that @FShrike, I've switched the arguments of the Hom-space! Unfortunately the question's been closed so I'm not sure I'll be able to see your answer, which I was/am looking forward to. I really can't say I agree with the closure reasoning, as I think the post invites an interesting discussion but I am open to suggestions.

Luckily, I snuck in there. I didn't spend 30 minutes figuring out how the equivariance works for myself for nothing. The answer is ready

Thanks again for your answer @FShrike! I've cobbled together what I think is a correct basis-free proof of the claim in the original post above. As for the moderators' insistence that this post should remain closed, it is frankly quite baffling and off-putting.

Question re-opened... hooray!

! I've made some edits. I agree a basis free proof is actually very readily available, I've offered my own and left some comments about internal homs

EDIT: I was a little frazzled when writing this post originally. I've just realised, of course, that $V^\ast\otimes_k W\cong\hom_k(V,W)$ not only as $k$-vector spaces but as $G$-representations (this is clear from the explicit map I provide) in the finite dimensional case; therefore, without appealing to bases - much as you have done in your edited question - one can very reasonably expect $\hom_k(V,W)^G=\hom_G(V,W)$ as $k$-vector subspaces of $\hom_k(V,W)$ and this is easily seen. $T:V\to W$ is $G$-invariant iff. $g\circ T\circ g^{-1}=T$ for all $g$ (by definition of how $g$ should act on $\hom_k(V,W)$) or $g\circ T=T\circ g$ for all $g$, $g(T(v))\equiv T(g(v))$ i.e. iff. $T$ is a morphism of $G$-representations. But I'll leave the basis-heavy proof here anyway, since finite dimensionality - of $W$, at least - is needed for $V^\ast\otimes_k W\cong\hom_k(V,W)$, so we don't lose much.
As for tensor-hom duality and enriched homs, well, the category $\mathcal{R}_{k,G}=\mathsf{Vect}_k^{B[kG]}$ of $G$-representations over $k$ is a functor category between two $k$-enriched categories, the domain category being small and $\mathsf{Vect}_k$ being bicomplete, so by generalities the category of $G$-representations over $k$ is itself a $k$-enriched category. And, explicitly, the enriched hom functor $\underline{\mathcal{R}_{k,G}^{\mathsf{op}}\otimes\mathcal{R}_{k,G}}\to\mathsf{Vect}_k$ is just, of course, $\hom_G(-,-)$. But even better! This lifts further up the chain, as $\mathcal{R}_{k,G}$ is itself a symmetric monoidal category with internal hom the $G$-representation $\hom_k(V,W)$, $g\cdot T:=g\circ T\circ g^{-1}$; furthermore, there is a notion of a 'change of base' in enriched category theory (a change of cosmos, really) and the theorem (which doesn't need finite-dimensionality) $(\hom_k(V,W))^G=\hom_G(V,W)$ suggests to us that change-of-base along the $G$-invariants functor $\mathcal{R}_{k,G}\to\mathsf{Vect}_k$, which is a right adjoint, transfers the enriched structure of $\mathcal{R}_{k,G}$ over itself to its enrichment over $k$.

In the finite-dimensional case it is well known in (multi)linear algebra that: $V^\ast\otimes_kW\cong\hom(V,W)$. This is a natural isomorphism; both sides are covariant in $W$ and contravariant in $V$, and the isomorphism can be constructed without reference to bases. It is simply the map which, on pure tensors, looks like $\psi\otimes w\mapsto(v\mapsto\psi(v)\cdot w))$. Therefore, in linear algebra it holds that: $\hom_k(k,V^\ast\otimes_kW)\cong\hom_k(k,\hom(V,W))\cong\hom_k(V,W)$.
If we take into account $G$-equivariance, does this isomorphism remain correct? Aye. But one must be careful; for instance, $V^\ast\otimes_kW\cong\hom_G(V,W)$ doesn't make sense anymore. We must also be evil (I think) and fix bases. I would love to see a basis-free proof. We must be extremely careful, in fact, with the direction of the variance. The previous version of this answer tried to prove $\hom_G(V^\ast\otimes_kW,k)\cong\hom_G(V,W)$ and while this is true if $G$-equivariance is ignored, it is false otherwise!
Fix bases for $V,W$ over the ground field $k$, $(v_i)$ and $(w_i)$. Let $\psi_i$ denote the dual basis of $V^\ast$ i.e. $\psi_i(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$. A morphism $F:k\to V^\ast\otimes_kW$ of representations is the data of scalars $(\sigma_{i,j}\in k)_{i,j}$ such that $\sum_{i,j}\sigma_{i,j}\psi_i\otimes w_j$ is $G$-invariant. This means to say $\sum_{i,j}\sigma_{i,j}(\psi_ig^{-1})\otimes gw_j=\sum_{i,j}\sigma_{i,j}\psi_i\otimes w_j$, or - if the matrix actions of $g$ on $V$, $W$ with respect to these bases are $M_g$ and $N_g$ - the condition: $$(\dagger):\quad\sigma_{i,j}=\sum_{k_1,k_2}\sigma_{k_1,k_2}\cdot(M_g)^{-1}_{k_1,i}(N_g)_{j,k_2}$$This comes from changing variables to avoid confusion in: $\sum_{k_1,k_2}\sigma_{k_1,k_2}(\psi_{k_1}g^{-1}\otimes(gw_{k_2})$ and then expanding the pure tensors $\psi_{k_1}g^{-1}\otimes gw_{k_2}$ in the basis $(\psi_i\otimes w_j)_{i,j}$.
Fortunately, the canonical basis of $\hom_k(V,W)$ (as a matrix space) is exactly the image of the isomorphism $V^\ast\otimes_kW$ on the canonical basis $(\psi_i\otimes w_j)_{i,j}$. They map to the linear maps $\sum_r \lambda_r v_r\mapsto \lambda_i w_j$, their matrix is all zeroes with a $1$ in the right slot. Let's call these maps $T_{i,j}$. Then, $F$ picks out the element $\sum_{i,j}\sigma_{i,j}T_{i,j}$ of $\hom_k(V,W)$.
We just have to check this element of $\hom_k(V,W)$ is $G$-equivariant iff. $F$ is, since we know this process makes an isomorphism of vector spaces $\hom_k(V^\ast\otimes_kW,k)\cong\hom_k(V,W)$. So we must check: $$(\dagger)\iff\sum_{k_1,k_2}\sigma_{k_1,k_2}T_{k_1,k_2}M_g\overset{?}{=}\sum_{k_1,k_2}\sigma_{k_1,k_2}N_gT_{k_1,k_2}$$As linear maps. Or: $$(\dagger)\iff\sum_{k_1,k_2}\sigma_{k_1,k_2}T_{k_1,k_2}\overset{?}{=}\sum_{k_1,k_2}\sigma_{k_1,k_2}N_gT_{k_1,k_2}(M_g)^{-1}$$Let's evaluate this on a basis element $v_i$ of $V$. The two sides yield: $$\sum_j\sigma_{i,j}w_j=\sum_{k_2}\sigma_{i,k_2}w_{k_2}\overset{?}{=}\sum_{k_1,k_2}\sigma_{k_1,k_2}N_g\cdot(M_g)^{-1}_{k_1,i}w_{k_2}=\sum_{k_1,k_2,j}\sigma_{k_1,k_2}(M_g)^{-1}_{k_1,i}(N_g)_{j,k_2}\cdot w_j$$And we can read off that $(\dagger)$ is indeed equivalent to this equation holding for all $k_1$.
Hence, the natural isomorphism $\hom_k(k,V^\ast\otimes_kW)\cong\hom_k(V,W)$ restricts to a natural isomorphism $(V^\ast\otimes_k W)^G\cong\hom_G(k,V^\ast\otimes_kW)\cong\hom_G(V,W)$ in the category of finite-dimensional $G$-representations.
